# NullPointerException when use getLaunchIntentForPackage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start a third party app(here is Launcher) by using this code:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            String currentHomePackage = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            openApp(getApplicationContext(),currentHomePackage);
```

openApp:

```
public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i == null) {

            return false;
            //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        }
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return false;
    }
}
```

but I get a `NullPointerException`! This code gets my launcher package name correctly, but I can't open it! Help me please and don't get me negative points!

logcat:

```
07-30 18:59:47.206  16079-16079/ir.whiteapp.keepme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ir.whiteapp.keepme.AlertBox.openApp(AlertBox.java:80)
        at ir.whiteapp.keepme.AlertBox$1.onClick(AlertBox.java:52)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your entire stack trace, and show what lines referred to in the stack trace correspond to lines in the code snippets that you show in your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare i==null is my problem, shouldnt be null because currentHomePackage is correct but i==null

Comment: Don't catch Exception ex , instead let the runtime exception stop your program, so you can see the stacktrace.

Runtime exceptions shouldn't be caught, you should prevent them from occurring.

Comment: @CommonsWare  logcat is added

Comment: @Joeblade logcat added

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` return anything. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns: A fully-qualified Intent that can be used to launch the main activity in the package. Returns null if the package does not contain such an activity, or if packageName is not recognized.

In particular, a home screen implementation does not need a launch `Intent` (`ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`), as normally it is not launched by other home screen implementations.

Comment: then how can i open default launcher in my app??

Comment: @MehdiAkin: The only activity that a home screen implementation has to have is `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME`. So, use `queryIntentActivities()` with `PackageManager` to try to find this activity, then create an `Intent` based upon its component name.